# How can i check the query execution plan?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sql-execution-plan

In the Java application we are developing when loading a page time out exceptions are been thrown. So i am assigned to investigate the issue. there are several database fetches that are happening when loading the page. So i want check which queries are running parallel and the execution plan. Whether there are any unnecessary joints and indexes. The data base is mysql and have used hibernate in the back-end.

So can anyone left me know how i can get the execution plan and check what queries are being  executed parallel.

Comment: Start by looking at mysql's Slow Query Log.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html Ask this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can define in your hibernate properties this.

```
            hibernate.format_sql=true
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```